# Dota 2 Wiki Character Responses

Tags: dota-2

http://dota2.gamepedia.com has some really nice pages that give you all or most of the hero responses that you may be able to hear in a game. That's really cool.

Here's the issue, I have no idea what these little tooltips mean on the site. I'm really curious as to what they mean. For example, let's take a sample of [Crystal Maiden's page](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Crystal_Maiden_responses):

[image]

You can see things without tool tips, and with them in various flavors (60, u, r, etc). I don't really see a key for these tips anywhere on the site, and clicking them does nothing.

Does anyone know the meaning behind these tags?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about support for a specific website, not a game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably is a problem with the website. You can see what these stand for by inspecting the element. They stand for:

`u` stands for `Unused Response`.

`60` stands for `60 seconds cooldown`.

Comment: Oh. I see that now. I inspected the element and I can't see it, yet I can definitely see if I view the source. Must be a add-on acting funky on me and removing it. http://imgur.com/rYjtd5j.jpg